# Rotate image inside a button UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to rotate a font icon inside a button 90° in the first click and back to 0° on the second click.

Currently I have:

```
 <Page.Resources>
   <Storyboard x:Name="RotateButton90Degrees">
        <DoubleAnimation
            EnableDependentAnimation="True"
            Storyboard.TargetName="ShowSubTasks_ButtonRotateTransform"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
            From="0"
            To="90"
            Duration="350" />
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>
<Button
   x:Name="ShowSubTasks_Button"
   Background="Transparent">
   <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
       <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
           <media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource RotateButton90Degrees}" />
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
   </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
   <FontIcon
      FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
      Glyph="&#xE974;"
      RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
      <FontIcon.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="ShowSubTasks_ButtonRotateTransform" />
       </FontIcon.RenderTransform>
   </FontIcon>
</Button>
```

The problem is that the app crashes when I click the button (it's not finding the ShowSubTasks_ButtonRotateTransform). The second is that I don't know how to revert the rotation effect after the first click (first click -> 90°, second click -> 0°, third click -> 90° and so on).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to create two Storyboard and with the help of additional variable you can remember whether to rotate from 0->90 or 90->0 and accordingly call Storyboard. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19377202/3244198)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i got the problem, the thing is that im running all that code inside a DataTemplate ... So that explains why its crashing. For the fix i used what @Dishant suggested, created two storyboards and with a DataTriggerBehavior i change the angle of the rotate transform

```
  <StackPanel.Resources>
      <Storyboard x:Name="RotateButtonTo90Degrees">
          <DoubleAnimation
              EnableDependentAnimation="True"
              Storyboard.TargetName="ShowSubTasks_ButtonRotateTransform"
              Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
              From="0"
              To="90"
              Duration="0:0:0.1" />
      </Storyboard>
     <Storyboard x:Name="RotateButtonTo0Degrees">
          <DoubleAnimation
              EnableDependentAnimation="True"
              Storyboard.TargetName="ShowSubTasks_ButtonRotateTransform"
              Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
              From="90"
              To="0"
              Duration="0:0:0.1" />
     </Storyboard>
 </StackPanel.Resources>
  <Button
     Background="Transparent"
     Visibility="{Binding HasSubTasks, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
      <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
           <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding ShowSubTasks, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
               <media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource RotateButtonTo90Degrees}" />
           </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
           <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding ShowSubTasks, Mode=OneWay}" Value="False">
                <media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource RotateButtonTo0Degrees}" />
           </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
      </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
      <FontIcon
           FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
           Glyph="&#xE974;"
           RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
           <FontIcon.RenderTransform>
              <RotateTransform x:Name="ShowSubTasks_ButtonRotateTransform" />
            </FontIcon.RenderTransform>
       </FontIcon>
  </Button>
```

Also as @MartinZikmund suggested, i needed to change the duration from 350 to something like 0:0:0.5

Answer (score 0):

In my case the app does not crash, but the icon does not rotate, because the duration is set to `350`, which basically means 350 hours. If you change this value to something like `0:0:0.5`, it should rotate in 0.5 seconds. To do the reverse animation, you would probably need to set the animation target programatically, but in such case you could just run the storyboard itself in the `Click` event handler.

If you are targeting Windows 10 15063 or higher, you can use [Implicit Animations in XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/animations/implicitanimations). In that case you could set up an implicit animation on the rotation of the icon and then just set the rotation property in the code-behind accordingly and implicit animation would take care of the animation itself.